# Blazor Server InputFile won't work in mobile

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Hi I am using the [InputFile](https://photos.google.com/album/AF1QipPjYxZGnFgqgcNX7InGivznHFt9cNQ0BU8yXGTM) component in Blazor Server (.NET 6) it works like a charm in desktop browsers but in mobile, it just doesn't work!

here is the code:

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
                        <label class="form-label">
                            @Localizer["pet-information-photograph"]
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-modal f-15 rounded-circle font-weight-bold white btn-sm" @onclick="@(() => ModalPetPhotograph())">?</button>
                        </label>
                        <InputFile class="form-control" OnChange="ProcessPhotographs" accept=".png,.pdf" />
                        <small>@Localizer["page-rus-petInformation-fileValidateSize"]</small>
                    </div>
```

and the method:

```js
 async Task ProcessPhotographs(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            photographBase64 = string.Empty;

            if (e.FileCount > 0)
            {
                foreach (var img in e.GetMultipleFiles(1))
                {
                    var arrbytes = new byte[img.Size];
                    try
                    {
                        if (img.Size < 1024000 && (img.ContentType.Contains("png") || img.ContentType.Contains("jpg") || img.ContentType.Contains("pdf")))
                        {
                            await img.OpenReadStream(1024000).ReadAsync(arrbytes);
                            photographBase64 = $"data:{img.ContentType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(arrbytes)}";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ToastService.ShowWarning(Localizer["page-petInformation-fileValidateSize"], Localizer["toast-warning"]);
                            isLoading = false;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ToastService.ShowWarning(Localizer["msg-toast-photograph"], Localizer["rus-toast-warning"]);
                isLoading = false;
                return;
            }
            additionalPet.Photograph = photographBase64;
        }
```

Any ideas, how to make it work for mobile?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/quain24/ScanApp/blob/master/ScanApp/Components/CamUploader.razor) code - it's a component from my app, I designed it for uploading pictures in blazor server. Uses MudBlazor buttons, but it should not matter to You in this case. It works on mobile also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, turns out that way I was reading the file was causing an issue, that after many attempts we depicted the faulty code and replace it for this:

```html
using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                        {
                            await img.OpenReadStream(1024000).CopyToAsync(ms);
                            var arrbytes = ms.ToArray();
```